# holding the commits and pulling a repository, and then pushing the commits

Tags: git

I am a git-beginner, so apologies for the naive question:

I am turning my local repo into a mess by doing the following:

changing things and committing them but not pushing. Now the repository on the server has been changed by some other users. What I ideally want to do is to ignore all my commits, pull the last version from the server, and then commit my change and then push. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: I'm a git beginner too! Most important thing to remember: you can't mess up anything with git, so just experiment. As long as you don't push a mistake to the server, you can undo everything. Even if you lose a commit somehow, you can get it back with `git reflog`. So don't worry, it gets easier :-)

Comment: I actually dont see any problem with what you are doing. Just do `git pull` and your local commits will be merged with remote commits. Its not necessary that you have to keep your local copy updated with remote before doing any changes. Git is cool, dont worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that only the master branch is involved, just do this:

```
$ git pull --rebase origin master
```

You will pull all changes to the master branch, with your commits rebased as if you had first pulled the new changes, and then, started making changes and committed.

You can also just

```
$ git pull
```

but you'll likely end up with a merge commit. I like to rebase first (or `pull --rebase`) to keep the history easier to read.

Check out these git tutorials: https://www.atlassian.com/git/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that only `master` branch is involved here.

First save the current work to a new branch

```
git checkout -b saved_branch
```

you can checkout to the commit you start with.

```
git checkout ab1234efbe
```

Then you can create a new branch base

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

Now pull in the changes made by others

```
git pull origin master
```

then you can merge

```
git merge saved_branch
```

Now you can push to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're doing fine.

There's many ways to fix this. I'll try to suggest one super simplistic solution :-)

Find a previous commit further down the history, either using SourceTree or `git log`, I guess the commit before your first local (non-pushed) commit.

Then note the commit ID (guid) of the last commit from the server you want to keep, and "throw away" your local commits while keeping your changes with `git reset --soft`:

```
git reset 6c747669c865e03c13027761569f02d930937ee4 --soft
```

Now your branch is back to the original state, and your changes are unstaged. Stage and stash your changes:

```
git add .
git stash
```

Now your master branch should be clean, in the original state. You should be OK to do a fetch/pull from origin now.

When your local repo is up to date with master, just apply your stash again (and consider that you may now have conflicts to resolve):

```
git stash apply
```

Some suggestions: use a GUI like [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) to view your local repo, but my personal suggestion: don't be tempted to use SourceTree to perform any actions (like committing or pushing). Use the command-line for any actions. Only use the GUI to view/visualize your repo history.

I also highly recommend using git-up (either the [Ruby](https://github.com/aanand/git-up) or [Python](https://github.com/msiemens/PyGitUp) version, depending on your platform. I use the PyGitUp one).

The first thing to realize when using Git, you can't really mess up anything (unless you push your mess to the server of course! :-)

You need to get comfortable with using local branches for your work, instead of working on the `master` branch. That will make it easier to rebase / merge in the future.

Comment: I would use `git stash save stash_name` to be sure I understand what this stash contains, when checking list of stashes with `git stash list`